# Microsoft Report number and string formatted date on same axis

Tags: c#, .net, reporting-services, microsoft-reporting

I have a Microsoft Report running on client (rdlc) on which I want to show a mix of years and month names for the category axis range. The data comes in a numeric format from my data base like 2011, 2012, 1, 2, 3, etc. I'm trying the expression below:

```
= IIF(Fields!Month.Value > 13, Fields!Month.Value, MonthName(Fields!Month.Value))
```

However instead of showing 2011, 2012, January, Febuary, March, it's only showing the months' names and hiding the years.

How can I get everything to show the way I need?

Thanks!

Comment: The expression you mention in the question only refers to the month field, so it's no surprise to me only months are shown. Shouldn't you have something like `Fields!Year.Value` mixed in there as well?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that both, year and month are coming via the field Month. A bit confusing but the way it is today.

Comment: Err... come again!? :S Then what kind of values does `Month` hold? Can you update the question with that info, and add some sample data for the data set?

Comment: It holds integers. Just drop the name Month and consider Period, instead. For example, for a given query, it returns 2010, 2011, 2012, 1, 2, 3, being 2010-2012 years and 1,2,3, months. What I want is to show the months names when the value is < 13 or just the value itself otherwise. So, the sequence above would be shown like this: 2010, 2011, 2012, January, February, March.

Comment: If the values in your Month or "Period" field are literally "2010,2011,2012,1,2,3" then what you have is a string, not a numeric value. If you want to apply a function such as MonthName to values in the string, you are going to have to parse out the individual numeric values first. Have you looked at maybe modifying your source query to see if you can return the month names in the dataset?